# Combining queries (But not combine fields or nested query)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index,
which has a text field, let say "content"
and I have another field, let say, "field1"

What I want is:
documents where content contains "searchterm" and field1 is excatly either "foo" or "bar".

simple_query_string is doing great on searching documents.
But how do I implement this combination? Is this even possible?

bool query is not working properly for text search.(or I understand it completly wrong)

I need simple_query_string operators (operators on query string itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to this.

The thing is, I was in need of simple_search_query operators, thus, boolean query was not a good fit for my use case.

So, there is, let say a "manual simple_search_query operators" within "query_string".

Here is my solution:

```
GET test_index/_search
{
    "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
        "query" : "content:(\"exact search string with spaces\") AND field1:(\"foo\" OR \"bar\")"
        }
    }
}
```

But now, I need an interpreter on backend. because I want my users to negate query by minus. (ex: foo bar -tar) foo and/or bar but not tar

Is there any better implementation?

Edit:
RDFMF (Read the manual first)
it turns out, querystring query is supporting everything simple_search_string does.
'+','-',phrases etc.
So, let say, user input is:

```
+quick brown^2 "calm fox" -forest
```

a **quick** and **calm fox** (as is) is must, **brown** boosts result, *forest* must not present.

this query directly works as intended.I felt ashemed for thinking I need to parse AND/OR etc.
And actually it becomes more complex withing few entries :)

and official documentation states:

> The familiar boolean operators AND, OR and NOT (also written &&, || and !) are also supported but beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used together.

I thought exactly vice-versa.